# How to Disable Text Block Border in WPF Data Grid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

[image]I am facing a problem with **TextBlock** in **DataGrid**.
I am unable to Disable the **Border** for **TextBlock**.
There is **No Property** with name **BorderThickness** For TextBlock.
           So how can we **Disable** Border of a TextBlock.

Here I am adding my sample Grid Cell Style

```
                               <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                        <Style.Triggers>                                               
                                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkTurquoise" />
                                                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Here I am adding my whole DataGrid Code

```
 <DataGrid Name="gridcancelled" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HeadersVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" Background="White"  Cursor="Hand"  MouseLeftButtonDown="gridcancelled_MouseLeftButton" Loaded="gridcancelled_Loaded" PreviewKeyDown="gridcancelled_PreviewKeyDown" RowHeight="44.9" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource BlueGridLine}" VerticalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource BlueGridLine}" BorderThickness="1.5,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Gray">

                                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                        <Style.Triggers>                                               
                                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkTurquoise" />
                                                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGrid.CellStyle>

                                <DataGrid.Resources>
                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="DarkTurquoise"/>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkTurquoise" />
                                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"></Setter>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="DataGridRow.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkTurquoise" />
                                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"></Setter>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGrid.Resources>

                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding billId}" Width="220">
                                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />                                         
                                            </Style>
                                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding billDate}" Width="210" >
                                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                </Style>
                                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding counterId}" Width="210">
                                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                </Style>
                                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cashierId}" Width="190" >
                                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                </Style>
                                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding dueAmount, StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}" Width="172">
                                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,60,0"/>                                                    
                                                </Style>
                                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
```

Here I am adding my PreviewKeyDown Event Code

```
    private void gridcancelled_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            if (gridcancelled.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                gridcancelled.SelectedIndex = gridcancelled.Items.Count - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                gridcancelled.SelectedIndex--;
            }
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            if (gridcancelled.Items.Count - 1 > gridcancelled.SelectedIndex)
            {
                gridcancelled.SelectedIndex++;
            }
            else if (gridcancelled.SelectedIndex == gridcancelled.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                gridcancelled.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please give me your Suggestions.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: give your code of datagrid. i'll edit that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @KyloRen   Please check I have added sample Code...

Comment: do you mean the border that displayed when the cell is focused?

Comment: where are the borders in your screen shot? @sagar

Comment: plz check I have added GUI ... Here my issue is I am providing navigation for my grid .When I am moving up and down arrows I am not getting focus for next row @safi

Comment: plz see under counter column  @KyloRen i want to move focus also when i am navigating Up and Down with arrows ...

Comment: @sagar dats not exactly a border. it's a focus indicator. do you want that gone?

Comment: can't we move that focus to next rows when I am navigating from up and down with Arrows ? @KyloRen

Comment: @sagar usually that's how it behaves. not sure what's wrong with your code. can you give your whole data grid code?

Comment: I have added my Complete DataGrid Code plz have a look into it @KyloRen ... I want to move focus  to the navigated row

Comment: @sagar It works fine with me. the focus box mouse to rows with my arrow keys. Hope You have not written any wrong code in your datagrid events. socially in PreviewKeyDown event.

Comment: Plz check once again my code I have added my preview keydown event code @KyloRen

Comment: @sagar it's your code in keydown event that doesn't allow focus to move forward. do you need to cancel this routing?

Comment: If I don't Set e.Handled=true its continuously executing @KyloRen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Change your code as following:

```
private void gridcancelled_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {               
            if (gridcancelled.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                gridcancelled.SelectedIndex = gridcancelled.Items.Count - 1;
                SetFocus(gridcancelled.SelectedIndex, gridcancelled.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex);                    
            }
            else
            {
                gridcancelled.SelectedIndex--;
            }                
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {                
            if (gridcancelled.Items.Count - 1 > gridcancelled.SelectedIndex)
            {
                gridcancelled.SelectedIndex++;
            }
            else if (gridcancelled.SelectedIndex == gridcancelled.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                gridcancelled.SelectedIndex = 0;                   

                SetFocus(gridcancelled.SelectedIndex, gridcancelled.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex);
            }               
        }
    }

    public void SetFocus(int SelectedIndex,int SelectedCellIndex)
    {
        var row = gridcancelled.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(SelectedIndex) as DataGridRow;

        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

        var cell = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(SelectedCellIndex) as DataGridCell;

        Keyboard.Focus(cell);
    }

    public T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);
        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
        {
            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = v as T;
            if (child == null)
            {
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
            }
            if (child != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return child;
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Now GUI issue is solved ... But KeyDown event is not firing @kylo Ren

Comment: With Out using KeyDown Event also its working fine ... but here My problem is I want to do some action when User Selects a Row and clicked on Enter keyword I need to do some Actions... so I thought  Its not possible with Key Down Event That's Why I have chosen Preview_KeyDown Event @kylo Ren

Comment: @sagar have you removed the PreviewKeyDown event?

Comment: Yes I have Removed @kylo Ren .      Now my grid contains only {MouseLeftButtonDown="gridcancelled_MouseLeftButton" Loaded="gridcancelled_Loaded"} Events

Comment: I want to perform some Actions in 2 cases ... one is when user clicked with mouse left button and other is when user selects a row and pressed Enter keyword ... Please  Give me your own suggestion what is the event I should Use ... @kylo Ren

Comment: Key Down Event is not firing for Enter , and Arrows Keys @KyloRen

Comment: @sagar wait a sec I'm giving you complete solution

Comment: @sagar see my updated answer for focus Issue. Hope that would be all. please optimize the code i just make it work and left that way

Comment: Thank you Sooooooo much @Kylo Ren Now its working fine

Comment: @sagar No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

your problem is with `FocusVisualStyle`

```
   <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkTurquoise" />
                                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <Rectangle Margin="-2" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Red"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Comment: Sorry @safi Still I am unable to move focus to the navigated Row .I want to get focus to the navigated Row ...

Comment: @sagar give the PreviewKeyDown event code also. If you have written any code in there

Comment: Plz check once again my code I have added my preview keydown event code @KyloRen